# Move selected email to folder based on InputBox value

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move emails based on value in InputBox.

Idea is, I select one or more emails and run script.

- InputBox appears and I fill in 6 digits representing a folder name.
- If the folder exists anywhere in Outlook inbox move the selected emails to this folder.
- If the folder doesn't exist, then MsgBox (No such folder).
- If the folder exists more then once, then MsgBox (Multiple records).

Comment: In order to be your „first” Outlook code, please make some research on internet and show us what you tried by your own. Even if it does not do exactly what you need...

Comment: I've make some codes for excel in the past, but outllok VBA is new for me. I've also trz to search now web, but most of the codes using for moving email text from subject, or if they use input box, they manage to copy to folder in PC. So Im little bit confused and dont know where to start.

Comment: Just like here: https://www.msofficeforums.com/outlook/18295-outlook-vba-move-selected-email-public-folder.html

Comment: And did you test the solution suggested there? If you tried something (from there, or from somewhere else), you should edit your question, post the code and explain where you got into trouble. An error, error message, no message but it does not do what you need etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method of the `MailItem` (or any Outlook items) for moving selected items to a folder. To find out which items are selected in Outlook you could use the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property of the `Explorer` class which returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window.

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
 Dim mySender As Outlook.AddressEntry 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 Dim MsgTxt As String 
 Dim x As Long 
 
 MsgTxt = "Senders of selected items:" 
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
   If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then 
     ' For mail item, use the SenderName property. 
     Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x) 
     MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.SenderName & ";" 
   ElseIf myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then 
     ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property. 
     Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x) 
     MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oAppt.Organizer & ";" 
   End If 
 Next x 
 
 Debug.Print MsgTxt 
 
End Sub
```

For example, the following code locates items from a specific sender and then moves them to a subfolder:

```
Sub MoveItems() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items 
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Personal Mail") 
 Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'Eugene Astafiev'") 
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing" 
 myItem.Move myDestFolder 
 Set myItem = myItems.FindNext 
 Wend 
End Sub
```

To find the folder in Outlook you need to iterate over all folders recursively.  The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method to find a folder by its name. See [Enumerate folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-enumerate-folders) for more information.